# Responsive design up to 320px?

Tags: iphone, responsive-design, css

I don't know why my responsive design isn't working for a size with max-width of 320px. I'm trying different sizes for iPad in Chrome and works properly but for iPhone goes wrong. My code is the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/iPhonePortrait.css" media="only screen and (max-width : 320px) and (orientation : portrait)" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/iPadLandscape.css" media="only screen and (max-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape)" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/iPadPortrait.css" media="only screen and (max-width : 768px) and (orientation : portrait)" />
```

The browser is updated, any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this as your meta tag`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">`.

Comment: Thanks Adam, between the cookies and your remark I got the correct resize. At the end, as meta tag I used <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" /> and works properly as well.